# Why is text vertically aligned in CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-grid

I am trying to add 2 images with different heights and some text (height of text is different). I'm using Grid to create same height for divs with images (don't want to use height, because I don't know the height of images).

I don't know why, when I use `display:grid` the text is aligned in middle of the div. Some idea? I wasn't able to find out why.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.magazine-items {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: start
}

.magazine-item {
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.magazine-item img {
  width: 100%;
}

.double-text {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="magazine-items">
  <div class="magazine-item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://www.onlinekoupelny.cz/image/catalog/magazin/ELLE-EFFE_small.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Porovnání detailů designu série Elle a Effe</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="magazine-item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://www.onlinekoupelny.cz/image/catalog/magazin/Level_small.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Vyvážené linie s citem pro maximální funkčnost, zaoblené tvary a nadčasová elegance činí z řady Level jednu z nejoblíbenějších sérií značky Paffoni. Vyvážené linie s citem pro maximální funkčnost, zaoblené tvary a nadčasová elegance činí z řady
        Level jednu z nejoblíbenějších sérií značky Paffoni.Vyvážené linie s citem pro maximální funkčnost, zaoblené tvary a nadčasová elegance činí z řady Level jednu z nejoblíbenějších sérií značky Paffoni.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not really aligned but this is the logical result of the grid calculation since you didn't define any template. Inspect the element to better see

Comment: @TemaniAfif and can I align it at top? My problem is that I won't know how many divs there's gone by. It can by 2 or more. So, I do't know how to define the template without knowing the number of divs

Comment: add `grid-template-rows:auto 1fr` (on the grid container) or use `align-items:flex-start`  (on the flex container)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Already tried it, but the left text goes upper than the right and that's beucase of the height of images, which are different (1189px and 1459px).

Comment: Try `.magazine-item {align-items : start}`

Comment: @RadekF  `.magazine-item {align-items : start}` has no effect. but when I use it on `magazine-items` text goes top, but is not at the same line as the second text (check the snippet). My problem is that I cannot use `height` property, becaue i want it to work on every image, no matter what is width and height

Comment: Do you have some css on the text class?

Comment: Nope. Maybe in the future. But now, it doesn't have any CSS

Answer (score 1):

`p` elements have default top and bottom margins.

These margins make your text appear centered in their containers.

[image]

Make them smaller or remove them.

Add this to your code:

```
p { margin-top: 0 }
```

You may also want to remove the [descender space below images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276).

Add this to your code:

```
img { vertical-align: bottom; }
```

```css
/* new */
p   { margin-top: 0; }
img { vertical-align: bottom; }


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.magazine-items {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: start
}

.magazine-item {
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.magazine-item img {
  width: 100%;
}

.double-text {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="magazine-items">
  <div class="magazine-item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://www.onlinekoupelny.cz/image/catalog/magazin/ELLE-EFFE_small.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Porovnání detailů designu série Elle a Effe</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="magazine-item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://www.onlinekoupelny.cz/image/catalog/magazin/Level_small.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Vyvážené linie s citem pro maximální funkčnost, zaoblené tvary a nadčasová elegance činí z řady Level jednu z nejoblíbenějších sérií značky Paffoni. Vyvážené linie s citem pro maximální funkčnost, zaoblené tvary a nadčasová elegance činí z řady
        Level jednu z nejoblíbenějších sérií značky Paffoni.Vyvážené linie s citem pro maximální funkčnost, zaoblené tvary a nadčasová elegance činí z řady Level jednu z nejoblíbenějších sérií značky Paffoni.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More information:

- [Flexbox vertical text alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41175624/3597276)
- [Equal height children of flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36721216/3597276)

Comment: Thanks, it goes up, but it's not at the same line as the second text (the text on right). How could I fix that?

Comment: I added link references to my answer that may assist you further. @ValentinEmilCudelcu